Why did Gwen evade Miles's question?
Miguel invites Spider-gang to Spider-HQ:

Gwen: Welcome to Spider-Society.

Camera pull back to reveal so many Spider-People:

Hobie: Bit much, init?
Miles: What happened to that small elite strike team?
Gwen: A lot of these are part-time.

It appears that Gwen did not directly answer Miles’s question about the
small elite strike team. Instead, she commented on the part-time nature
of many of the Spider-People, which could be seen as evading or sidestepping
the original question.
Why did Gwen evade Miles's question?

This is not a case of evading the question.

In an earlier scene, Miles pitches himself as a potential member of the Spider Society. Gwen, who unbeknownst to Miles has already discovered that he's absolutely not welcome downplays how big the group is so that she doesn't need to explain why he's not wanted.

MILES: I’m just saying, if I had a watch I could come with you. I did save the
multi-verse!
GWEN: Miles, look, it’s a really small elite strike force.
MILES: I can turn invisible...
GWEN: There’s just--
MILES: I have like, electric powers--
GWEN: There aren’t a lot of slots.
[You know that sucky feeling when you’re not invited to that really cool thing?]
Spider-Man: Across the Spider-Verse screenplay

We then see that the Spider Society is not a small group, but in fact a very large and diverse group. This was what Gwen was trying to shield him from. It's not an especially selective grouping, but he's the least wanted of the whole Spider-verse variants because of what he did to the Multiverse (hint, not good things). Miguel has vetoed him.

GWEN: Miguel! It’s not his fault.
MILES: Fault? Hold up --
MIGUEL: YOU BLEW ANOTHER HOLE IN THE MULTIVERSE!!

